# cURL and Facebook problems

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I am using cURL to access a facebook page. Locally it works perfect, but when I upload it to my dev server, it breaks and returns an empty string. I've checked and cURL is installed on the server. Here's the code I use to access facebook:

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept: text/json';
$header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Pragma: ';

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=135137236003');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is php_curl enabled? you can find by echo phpinfo() and find the word curl if curl is not there

Comment: Have you tried curling other pages to rule out whether there's an issue between your server and facebook?

Comment: yes I've tried curling google (locally and on dev) and it works. Facebook works locally, but not on the dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the accept header to `*/*` or `application/json` as facebook is sending the response header as `application/json`.

And change this url

```
http://facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=135137236003
```

to

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=135137236003
```

as facebook is redirecting the non-www request to www requests. Though it works for you as put follow location, but it saves one reound trip

Comment: That was it. Any reason why the change is needed between local and dev server?

Comment: I guess its due to different versions of curl :)